# GMime multipart content

Tags: c, xml, soap

I am using the c version of the gmime library and having problems parsing and extracting content that seems to be already in multipart form. I thought parsing content as is gmime will figure out how to construct the multipart correctly so that simply performing

```
g_mime_multipart_get_part(mimeMessage, 0)
```

will return the soap-xml part. Clearly I'm wrong and my limited understanding of mime and gmime library is killing me. Please assist. Thanking you in advance.

```
GMimeStream * mimeStream = g_mime_stream_mem_new_with_buffer(incoming, n);
GMimeParser * mimeParser = g_mime_parser_new_with_stream(mimeStream);
g_object_unref(mimeStream);
GMimeMessage * mimeMessage = g_mime_parser_construct_message(mimeParser);
g_object_unref(mimeParser);
```

**RAW Content below*

```
------=_Part_5896175_1217116888.1478087584633
Content-Type: text/xml

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
...
</soap-env:Envelope>
------=_Part_5896175_1217116888.1478087584633
Content-Type: multipart/related;Start="<smil>";Type="application/smil";
    boundary="----=_Part_5896174_292278572.1478087584547"
Content-ID: /mms/mm7/mm7client

------=_Part_5896174_292278572.1478087584547
Content-Type: application/smil;Name=smil.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID:<smil>
Content-Location:smil.xml

<smil><head><layout><root-layout width="320px" height="480px"/><region id="Text" left="0" top="320" width="320px" height="160px" fit="meet"/></layout></head><body><par dur="0ms"><text src="text_0.txt" region="Text"/></par></body></smil>
------=_Part_5896174_292278572.1478087584547
Content-Type: text/plain;Name=text_0.txt;Charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID:<text_0>
Content-Location:text_0.txt

Your MMS was read 02 Nov 2016 13:53
------=_Part_5896174_292278572.1478087584547--

------=_Part_5896175_1217116888.1478087584633--
```

Answer (score 0):

GMime can't parse that because it's incomplete. How can the parser know what the multiparty boundary is if the content doesn't start with a Content-Type header that defines the boundary?